# Firefox Console

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm starting learn JavaScript on an Udemy MOOC but I can't find how to get this line:

[image]

Instead of this one:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to install [**Firebug**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) in order to get it.

Go to: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/

And click [`Add to FireFox`](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/latest/firebug/addon-1843-latest.xpi?src=dp-btn-primary)

After that you will get this icon on top right corner of Firefox:

[image]

Click on it and you will see the result:

[image]